# SQL query with encoded input parameter returns empty result in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-real-escape-string

I want to fetch a spare part from MySql (yii framework). Some part titles contain `'`, for
ex.: `OUTLANDER '03-06`
For securty reason i encode query string parameter thru `htmlspecialchars()` (converts special characters to HTML entities) to become query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM assortment
WHERE title LIKE "%OUTLANDER &#039;03-06 %"
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

yet **this yields an empty result**.

While if i only escape `'` by addign slash, such a query works:

```
SELECT *
FROM assortment
WHERE title LIKE "%OUTLANDER \'03-06 %"
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

What's the problem? Do i still need to apply `htmlspecialchars()` to input parameters to make them safe HTML entities cause of security reasons, what would be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use " mysql_real_escape_string() " instead.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp

Comment: I think that's what is needed. Another option is to use ENT_NOQUOTES to prevent encoding `'` and `"`
 `htmlspecialchars($input_string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

The function `htmlspecialchars()` does not meant to escape string in queries. You should use one of these functions:

- [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
- [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)